# Excluding packages from grails test-app?

Tags: grails, groovy, junit, grails-plugin

Is there a way to exclude packages from the default test-app runner? I have a set of long-running tests I want to run separate from other tests and I'm looking for a way to exclude a specific package from the running of `grails test-app`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot exclude, but you can include specific packages.  Which will still get you there.

[Grails Testing Docs](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#9.%20Testing)

Comment: I'd like to change the default behavior of test-app; I know I can run tests or packages individually.

Comment: Though it doesn't quite get you to exclusion, you can make rather liberal use of the * in dictating what to test in addition to specifying packages.

For example, `grails test-app *Foo*Service*` will run the test classes FooServiceSpec, FooBarServiceSpec, and FooBarServiceTest.

That may allow you to test the classes you want, but ignore those you don't, assuming they have some common elements in their class names.

Answer (score 1):

Grails support the concept of custom test types that lets yout separate tests into different custom types other that unit/integration/functional. See http://ldaley.com/post/615966534/custom-grails-test for how.

Comment: My initial input would also be to define a separate test type. This requires some extra changes in _Events.groovy as described in the post linked to by gogstad. You might run into problem when you want to run the specific tests with the Maven plugin.